# How do I select a specific line of data in MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

Im creating a program that will allow the management (me) to enter a clients information. The fields are as follows: ID, First Name, Last Name, Phone Num, Email, Street, City, State. Im trying to search the database using the first and last name of the client so only that row will show. (The specific clients information.)

Here's the function as is:

```
def filter_data(cur):
    name = input("Enter the clients' first and last name:")
    if name == "%s":

        try:

            cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM renters WHERE first_name = %s AND last_name = %s;''', name)
            cur.execute(name)
            results = cur.fetchone()

            if results:
                print("%-3s %-3s %-3s %-3s %-10s %23s %20s %15s" % ("ID:", "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "Email Address", "Street Address", "City", "State"))

            for row in results:
                cid, first, last, phone, email, street, city, state = row
                print("%-3s %3s %11s %13s %21s %27s %16s %7s" % (cid, first, last, phone, email, street, city, state))

                print()
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print(str(error), "Error occurred.")
            print("No data found.")
```

I've messed around with the fetch command and no input. I've messed with the SQL commands and no input. I've also used a print command for results prior to the second if statement, nothing printed. I've also made sure I was signed into the database and that it was connected. I think the issue lies on the actual SQL commands Im using or I'm missing something entirely.

Comment: well, i think the problem is you put the  `if name == "%s":` this condition before you exec sql, if your input not equals `%s`, you'll never get into to the `cur.execute`

Comment: There is another problem, you only Ask for name but not lastname, try to add `lastname=input('lastname: ')`. Then in your select query, add lastname to the liste, so it query name=name and last_name=lastname and not just name=name and last_name=name